# How to traverse the attribute name plus [i] to count？

Tags: javascript

For example, the object property name has a number, I want to add a property to the for traversal object, the property name must have a number.

**The printed results are as follows:**

```
[{
    room[1]: 1
  },
  {
    room[2]: 2
  },
  {
    room[3]: 3
  },
  {
    room[4]: 4
  },
  {
    room[5]: 5
  },
  {
    room[6]: 6
  }
]
```

```js
var = arr[]
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  arr.push({
    `room[${index}]`: index,
  })
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is missing something called [computed-property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

*Assuming there is a typo in the declaration of the variable `arr`*

```js
var arr = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  arr.push({
    [`room[${index}]`]/*Computed-property names*/: index,
  });
}
console.log(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  const obj = {};
  obj[`room[${index}]`] = index;
  arr.push(obj);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't store the rooms in an object array like this. Now you can add more properties to it so it is more flexible.

```js
const rooms = [
  { number: 1 },
  { number: 2 },
  { number: 3 },
  { number: 4 },
  { number: 5 },
  { number: 6 }
]

rooms.map(room => {
  console.log(room.number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help!

Just put int in `[]`

```
let arr = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
      arr.push({
          [`room[${index}]`]: index
      })
    }

    console.log(arr)
```